# ListBox does not return results

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to find out which cells within a range contain a certain string.

I have two columns:

[image]

I want the ListBox to return the Item number if the item description contains Italy.

I used this code in a user form:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
row_number = 1
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
 item_number = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)
 item_description = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number)


  If InStr(item_description, "italy,") > 0 Then
   UserForm.ListBox1.AddItem (item_number)

  End If
  Loop Until row_number = 423


End Sub
```

When I press F5 and run it I get nothing in return, Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

We can't see the text in column B, but I assume it contains "Italy", not "italy".

To compare using Instr but ignore case, you need to use:

```
If InStr(1,item_description, "Italy,",vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

---

According to Microsoft:

**InStr**([ *start* ], string1, string2, [ *compare* ])

Part     *Description*

**start**     *Optional*. Numeric expression that sets the starting position for each search. If omitted, search begins at the first character position. If start contains Null, an error occurs. *The start argument is required if compare is specified.*

**string1**     *Required*. String expression being searched.

**string2**     *Required*. String expression sought.

**compare**     *Optional*. Specifies the type of string comparison. If compare is Null, an error occurs. If compare is omitted, the Option Compare setting determines the type of comparison. Specify a valid LCID (LocaleID) to use locale-specific rules in the comparison.

Comment: is there a way to make it not case sensitive?

Comment: @Syd Use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Search()` to make it case insensitive.

Comment: The `vbTextCompare` part I added will make it not case sensitive. Replace your If line with mine at the start of this answer and it will be non case sensitive.

Comment: @Harun24HR - using Search is unnecessary. Instr has the option built in as a parameter, OP just need to use it.

Comment: i got this formula from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYR-LvMdevQ and there it seems to work fine

Comment: PS. Hitting F5 doesn't cause the code to run. You need to click (or add, then click) the button `CommandButton1` for this code to run and effect the Listbox.

Comment: Use Me to refer to the current form instance, not UserForm.

Comment: Check your form name `UserForm` may be `UserForm1`.

Comment: To reiterate. **Hitting F5 will NOT cause the code to run.**

Comment: yes i just hit f5 to show the box then i click on the button

Comment: we.tl/t-5DyejR2veR this is the file I'm using I really cannot get it to work

Comment: In your example file, all 422 rows of data contain "Italy,". So I added a Userform (called `Userform1`) and renamed it to `Userform` to match your code. I added a Listbox (called `Listbox1`) and a button. I swapped out the `If` line with my line and hit F5. The userform appears and I hit the button. The listbox populates with all 422 numbers from column A - albeit formatted to just the # without the zero-padding.

Comment: Thank that is amazing do you know what can I do to transfer the content of the Listbox to a sheet or simply to copy it?

Comment: That sounds like a 'new question' to me.. raise a new one and go from there.